# Airflow wasb_default config

Tags: airflow, azure-blob-storage

What is the correct format of wasb_defautl config?
I'm trying the following:

```
Host: https://<blob storage acc>.blob.core.windows.net
Schema: <empty>
login: <empty>
Password: <empty>
Port: <empty>
Extra: {"sas_token": "<blob storage account key1>"}
```

When I run DAG I'm constantly receiving:
ValueError: You need to provide an account name and either an account_key or sas_token when creating a storage service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use Airflow to connect Azure Blob storage, please make sure that a Airflow connection of type `wasb` exists. Authorization can be done by supplying a login (=Storage account name) and password (=KEY), or login and SAS token in the extra field. For more details, please refer to [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/integration.html#azure-blob-storage) and [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/tests/providers/microsoft/azure/hooks/test_wasb.py)

For example

```
Conn Type : wasb
login : <account name>
password: <account key>
```